# Objective-C retain / release snippet

Tags: objective-c, memory-management, singleton

Here are some snippets I coded and I would like some feedback on my way of handling this:

I have a utility class, as a singleton, that provides me with a method named `randomColor` which returns a `(UIColor*)`:

```
-(UIColor*)randomColor
{
    float l_fRandomRedColor = [[MathUtility instance] randomFloatNumberBetweenNumber:0.0f AndNumber:1.0f];
    float l_fRandomBlueColor = [[MathUtility instance] randomFloatNumberBetweenNumber:0.0f AndNumber:1.0f];
    float l_fRandomGreenColor = [[MathUtility instance] randomFloatNumberBetweenNumber:0.0f AndNumber:1.0f];

    return [UIColor colorWithRed:l_fRandomRedColor
                    green: l_fRandomGreenColor
                    blue: l_fRandomBlueColor
                           alpha: 255];
}
```

Now, I know the object return by this method is `autoreleased`.

I store the returned value in another class and I would like to keep this value for a while, so I proceed like this:

```
[self setMpCurrentPieceColor:[[GraphicsUtility instance] randomColor]];
```

Which calls the following property:

```
- (void)setMpCurrentPieceColor:(UIColor*)_newColor
{
    [_mpCurrentPieceColor release];
    [_newColor retain];

    // Make the new assignment.
    _mpCurrentPieceColor = _newColor;
}
```

**Question A)**

My instance variable is released in the dealloc method. Is a the correct way to go?

**Question B)**

Now, let's imagine I have an array, like this:

```
UIColor* mBoardColors[WIDTH][HEIGHT];
```

I want to store the previous instance variable into the array:

```
[mBoardColors[l_iBoardXIndex][l_iBoardYIndex] release];
[_color retain];
mBoardColors[l_iBoardXIndex][l_iBoardYIndex] = _color;
```

Is it correct?

**Question C)**

What if I want to move a color from a cell to another (moving, not copying), is it correct to do it like that?

```
[mBoardColors[l_iBoardXIndex][l_iBoardYIndex] release];
mBoardColors[l_iBoardXIndex][l_iBoardYIndex] = mBoardColors[l_iBoardXIndex][l_iBoardYIndex - 1];
mBoardColors[l_iBoardXIndex][l_iBoardYIndex - 1] = nil;
```

Thank in advance for your precious comments and advices!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, there's a number of simplifications to the Utility Class I'd like to make before I continue:

Your abstraction from `arc4random` (at least that's what I hope it is), is too expensive to not just use the corresponding C-code directly.  You could even make your own method in C, and use the inline qualifier for faster code than calling out to a singleton 3 times for every color.  Also, it is never good to name an Objective-C method "instance".  Singletons usually use a naming convention that makes sense with their overall implementation (i.e. `NSFileManager.defaultManager`).  The following will generate a random `double` for you between 0 and 1.  Not only is it cleaner, but it's cheaper.

```
#define ARC4RANDOM_MAX      0x100000000
float l_fRandomRedColor = ((double)arc4random() / ARC4RANDOM_MAX);
```

<sub>*As an aside, it's also a good idea to use an alpha value of 1.0f, instead of 255, because alpha is also measured on a 0-1 scale</sub>

> Question A)
>
> My instance variable is released in the dealloc method. Is a the
>   correct way to go?

The rule in ObjC is "You own it, you destroy it."  Because `mpCurrentPieceColor` is an explicitly `retain`'ed property, you own it.  If you were to not destroy `mpCurrentPieceColor` in `-dealloc`, then your class would retain a valid reference to it, and it simply would not go away. (memory leak).

<sub>*As an aside, switching to ARC will alleviate all of these headaches.</sub>

> Question B)
>
> Now, let's imagine I have an array, like this:
>
> UIColor* mBoardColors[WIDTH][HEIGHT];...

So long as you initialize the members of the multi-dimensional array, this is *correct*, but definitely not optimal.  Objective-C has it's own array objects, which free you from having to make these ridiculous memory management decisions, and a dynamic, expandable multidimensional array is as simple as nesting NS(Mutable)Arrays:

```
[NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:[NSArray array],[NSArray array],[NSArray array],[NSArray array],..., nil];
```

Not only that, but if you were to decide to expand or contract the board at any time, you could add or remove objects at a whim, and, so long as you release any references to the objects you put into the array, when the main array is released, it will release the sub-arrays, and the sub-arrays will release their objects.  It really is quite beautiful.

> Question C)
>
> What if I want to move a color from a cell to another (moving, not
>   copying), is it correct to do it like that?

Another beauty of NSArrays is the ability to swap-out objects into a new index of the array, so long as you don't exceed the array's bounds.  See the ["Replacing Objects"](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableArray_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000138-SW4) section of NSMutableArray's documentation.  Again, as above, memory management is vastly simplified with an NSArray, than dropping down to a multi-dimensional literal.

Answer (score 1):

Your setter looks a little unsafe and could lead to a crash in this case:

```
[self setMpCurrentPieceColor:_mpCurrentPieceColor];
```

A better version of the setter is synthesized setter, but if you need to change set behavior (add validation, update connected fields etc.) you can use next pattern:

```
- (void) setMpCurrentPieceColor:(UIColor *)newColor
{
    if (_color == newColor) return; // No need to do anything if same value transferred
    // Update value
    [_color release];
    _color = newColor;
    [_color retain];
}
```

Anyway, better use ARC and not fill your mind with memory management